# How to ensure script is run successfully as a transaction

Tags: shell-script

Suppose I have a script like this:

```
command1 params
command2 params
command3 params
```

Now, as I understand, each of those commands will run independently of the return status of the previous one. But I want them all to run as a single transaction, i.e. if any previous command fails the script:

1. should not proceed
2. ideally revert actions done by previous commands

For the first question, I understand, that I can use `&&` operator and chain all commands with it, or put if checks for `$?` after each command, but are these approaches the only options?

And what is the standard approach for the second question?

Comment: What if the command is `rm somefile‘?

Comment: @JeffSchaller ... or outputs text to `stdout`.

Comment: The rolling back is not possible automatically, you would have to invent logic for that yourself.

Comment: It depends a lot on the details of what you want to do with what privileges. It would be conceivable that you start by creating a LVM snapshot of all relevant partitions at the beginning, though I'd probably not do an automatic rollback that way on failure. (If failure is rare, it might be enough to know you have a disk state an admin can revert back to with manual intervention.)
None of this applies if you're just an ordinary user who wants to do something transactionally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An alternative to chaining the commands together with `&&` would be to run the script, or the section of the script, or sub-shell, with the `-e` option set (`set -e`, sometimes called the `errexit` option).  This would cause the script or sub-shell to simply exit on an error:

```
( set -e
  command1
  command2
  command3 )
```

As for a rollback of already executed steps, this is probably impossible to achieve in a shell script.

Take, for example, a script that performs an `exit` or a system reboot, or even manipulates data on disk:

```
( set -e
  if (( $# == 0 )); then
    echo "No command line arguments!" >&2
    exit
  fi
  echo "We're cool"
  false )

( set -e
  case "$cmd" in
    restart)  sudo reboot ;;
    greet)    echo "Hi there" ;;
    *)        echo "Huh?" ;;
  esac
  false )

( set -e
  rm -f /tmp/important_tmp_file
  echo "oh oh"
  false )
```

There would not be any way of rolling back an `exit` from having been executed, or a reboot from having been performed, or to undelete a file automatically.  Notice, too, that output to the terminal is also out of the hands of the shell and can't be called back.

Comment: thanks, is there any mechanism to jump to some error handling block of commands on error? Something similar to `try catch` in programming languages?

Comment: @Maximus There's the `ERR` trap.  Using `trap 'some_function' ERR` will call `some_function` in the same situations where `set -e` will call `exit` (with `set -e`, the script or subshell will still exit, even if you `trap` the `ERR`).

Comment: @Maximus ... it's not quite the same, but that's what's there.

Comment: no problem, I'll read about it in depth